# Using Eclipse CDT parser outside of CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, parsing, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to use Eclipse's CDT parser outside of Eclipse, to analyze C sources off line?

Comment: Are you just looking for C code analysis packages, or do you specifically want to use CDT?

Comment: @IraBaxter just an open source C code analysis, and the closest one I could think of is eclipse CDT (yes, I've seen your product, this is more or less what I'm looking for, but as a proof of concept I want to start with something open source).

Comment: There's CIL, FramaC, and GCC if you want open source versions.

Comment: @IraBaxter, nope, all mentioned offers different things. Specifically, they don't keep source mapping, and consume only preprocessed input. I don't need too fancy analysis, just make sure that every call to `lock()` has no `return` statements in scope, and an `unlock` call at the end.

Comment: "Don't keep source mapping"? All 3 of those tools purpose in life is to analyze programs for faults, and print a diagnostic when one is found. Crucial to a good diagnostic is reporting of line numbers.  I'm pretty sure they track the source code line numbers, if that's what you mean.

Comment: ... if you want to ensure that every lock is followed by an unlock, you're likely to need control flow analysis and a global call graph.  That leaves GCC, and I think CIL, out.  FramaC might do it.  (DMS can do it).  Dunno if CDT does flow analysis, I suspect not.

Comment: @IraBaxter I'm not trying to get a know-all super wise analysis, I want a simple human understandable analysis, with false positives. For instance, given a parsed C file, it is not hard to find out whether a `lock` is followed by an `unlock` at the end of the *same* scope. Yes, I do not allow to tuck unlock inside both `if` and `else` section, and thus I generate false positives, but I don't care. I want *all* locks follow this simple guidline. I don't need CFG for that. There are many such low hanging fruits, with much benefit and low cost. (Note that I can do it without even preprocessing).

Comment: If you don't care about false positives or false negatives, any you only want to check for existence of an unlock if there's a lock call  in function bodies, you can hack that with Perl in an hour (find matching {..}, check for lock/unlock inside).  You don't need a real parser.    This kind of tool can be helpful, but the false positive disease is a real curse: most tools that produce too many false positives get rejected as time-wasters eventually, and the only cure to false positives is better information. Eventually you end back up at the precise parser solution.  YMMV.

Comment: @IraBaxter, of course lock and unlock are not the only low hanging fruits, there are many application specific "rules" we want to make "no blocking functions in the GUI thread", for instance, and there will be more as we go. From sore experience, trying to hack a semiparser with perl or so is not the way to go, it kinds-of-work, but needs so much more work you're better off not use parser. And it wouldn't allow refactoring. Yes, full-fledged code analysis can be useful (and it of course also has many false positives as well), but application specific rules are also a big gain.

Comment: To do things like "no blocking functions in GUI thread" you have to be able to *find* the GUI thread and track down all the functions in it.  To do that is hopeless without a precise parser, a full symbol table, and flow analysis.  To do *refactoring* you need all that and the ability to transform code.   CDT certainly is much closer than perl for this. CIL, FramaC and GCC fail; they don't transform code.  I guess you're back to investigating CDT.  I don't know if it has flow analysis.

Comment: @IraBaxter "100% no blocking functions in GUI" indeed requires a full fledge flow analysis, and is likely wrong in some extreme cases in your product as well. But a simple warning if you call a function marked as blocking (from a list of known dangerous functions, or with `@//nogui` in comment) from a function with "gui" in its name, is still *immensely* useful, and does not require full fledged analysis. I don't understand why do you treat that as an "all or nothing" situation, many product gives heuristical analysis (see viva64), and are very useful.

Comment: Don't think our flow analysis is *wrong*; it is surely *conservative* to avoid the Turing tarpit; yes that leads to false positives.  I don't think of this as all or nothing; I do think that any serious analysis does parse and makes at least some weak attempt at dataflow (Viva64 does this).  Ultimately the payback has to do with your ambitions for analysis and your degree of willingness to accept answers that aren't quite right (for our product too), agreed.  Best of luck.

Comment: @IraBaxter just two notes, many Viva64 analysis does not require CFG, for instance, two identical `if`s, those simple heuristics catch boatloads of bugs, and are possible only with sane enough parser. The other note is, that implementing basic CFG is not THAT hard once you have a decent parser (maybe C++ implicit conversions are culprit, but in C it's not that hard, and it can be reasonable accurate with sane C++ codebase (assuming it's not an oxymoron)).

Comment: I looked at Viva64 ... claimed to be based on VivaCore, which does not have any flow analysis.  Maybe they added it; maybe not.  I think CFG is harder to do that you think; for C alone you have worry carefully about sequence points, gotos, SETJMP, assembly inclusions, etc.  For C++, you need to cover implicit conversions, constructor, destructors (the rule for these are surprisingly complex), exception handling, and overloads.  If you think these are not that hard, my hat is off to you, it was hard enough for us.  I think your point is you don't have to have it all to get value.  I agree...

Comment: ... with the proviso that to the extent your analyses are not based on precise semantics (e.g. "huerisitic") the diagnoses with be that much less trustworthy.  If that works for you, great.  The general experience in the static analysis tools business is that as false positives rises, tool acceptance drops very rapidly.  You only have to waste a programmer's time once to make him mad at you.

Comment: You can look at this http://www.inf.unibz.it/~gsucci/publications/full%20text/full%20text/OSS12.pdf document. I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I work in a project called [CPAchecker](http://cpachecker.sosy-lab.org) which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not constraint to use Eclipse CDT I recommend you to use clang/llvm. It is a fairly young compiler and code analyzer, but it has good performance.

[1] http://clang.llvm.org/
[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang

Answer (score 0):

You can set up eclipse CDT parser as a service.  Then you can pass your C code to it and have the code analysed. I have done similar things, except that I use jdt instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your precise scenario, you can have a look at Eclim and/or its implementation. It runs a headless eclipse and connects to it using the vim editor. Apparently it also supports other frontends. C/C++-Projects seem to be supported: http://eclim.org/vim/c/project.html

Otherwise, I'd go with @Dodon Victor and recommend clang/llvm.